# library/API recommendation for adding instrumentation in code

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, wmi

If I want to add some instrumentation in my code for getting metrics like how long a particular method took to execute, anyone has recommendation for either windows build-in or any 3rd party library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this done with PostSharp AOP framework, hooked into Windows Performance Counters (`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`).  One of their introductory pieces of sample code shows how to do this:

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/performance

This might be a good option if you want to deploy these measurements to production and measure performance in a live manner (to do diagnosis of a running system).

If you just want to locate bottlenecks in your code, and don't need to do live diagnosis, I suggest you simply use a profiler, such as the one built into VS or [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) (as Chris already suggested).  Then run a redacted copy of your production data against your code so your performance measurements match production.

Comment: I don't need to necessarily monitor these in real-time. My problem is that an application is running at 10 different customer locations. And a given functionality is running slow 3 out of those 10 locations. I cannot profile the application at those customer locations but if i have some type of instrumentation it will give me some idea of what methods are taking long time.

Comment: @Silverlight: If it is already running and you can't redeploy then you may be stuck.  But if you can redeploy, then perf counters are the standard way to go, and you can instrument your code with those perf counters via AOP.  I used "real time" in the wrong sense here - what I mean is that you can take live measurements against calls in a running system rather than relying on duplicating the same scenarios offline.  I've edited my answer to remove the incorrect term :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want this at runtime, you should probably use a profiler offline.  I'd avoid doing any instrumentation where possible as it takes time and therefore causes more performance problems.

Google for RedGate ANTS Profiler or JetBrains dotTrace.  If you have VS2010 Premium, it has one built in.  That will give you a method-level breakdown of what is happening time-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a profiler will take care of measuring performance.

If you need to measure time yourself StopWatch with some sort of tracing is often enough.